# Can't get desired results from Compare-Object

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powercli

Sample code:

```
$hosts    = Get-View -ViewType hostsystem -Property name,network
$clusters = Get-View -ViewType clustercomputeresource -Property name,network,host

$hosts | Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name TEST -value MoRef
$clusters | Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name TEST -Value Host
```

I would like to speed my scripts when parsing data and want to use `Compare-Object`.

However, the code

```
Compare-Object $hosts $clusters[0] -Property TEST -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -PassThru
```

is giving no output.

The code

```
Compare-Object $hosts.test $clusters[0].test -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -Pass -PassThru
```

is giving me exact matches, but not passing through the objects.

Unfortunately I cannot determine why.

Comment: Your last code snippet has a spurious `-Pass` in it. Other than that both `Compare-Object` statements worked fine for me. Can you provide sample data (in CSV form)?

Answer (score 0):

In the line `$hosts | Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name TEST -value MoRef` you are trying to set an alias property MoRef, but for hosts in the first line `$hosts    = Get-View -ViewType hostsystem -Property name,network` you are not selecting this property, so this alias cannot be set.

Please check if the objects to compare are both containing the correct information.

The line: `Compare-Object $hosts.test $clusters[0].test -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -Pass -PassThru` will give an error because both `-Pass` and `-PassThru` are in this line of code. 
This line will not passing through the object, because you are only comparing one property and not the whole object.

`Compare-Object $hosts $clusters[0] -Property TEST -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -PassThru` looks fine and I think this should work when the parameters are complete.